# Is there a way to prevent dtype from changing from Int64 to float64 when reindexing/upsampling a time-series?

Tags: python, pandas, types, resampling, reindex

I am using pandas 0.17.0 and have a `df` similar to this one:

```
df.head()
Out[339]: 
                       A     B  C
DATE_TIME                        
2016-10-08 13:57:00  in   5.61  1
2016-10-08 14:02:00  in   8.05  1
2016-10-08 14:07:00  in   7.92  0
2016-10-08 14:12:00  in   7.98  0
2016-10-08 14:17:00  out  8.18  0

df.tail()
Out[340]: 
                       A     B  C
DATE_TIME                        
2016-11-08 13:42:00  in   8.00  0
2016-11-08 13:47:00  in   7.99  0
2016-11-08 13:52:00  out  7.97  0
2016-11-08 13:57:00  in   8.14  1
2016-11-08 14:02:00  in   8.16  1
```

with following `dtypes`:

```
print (df.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
C      int64
dtype: object
```

When I reindex my `df` to minute intervals all the columns `int64` change to `float64`.

```
index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq="min") 
df2 = df.reindex(index)

print (df2.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
C    float64
dtype: object
```

Also, if I try to resample

`df3 = df.resample('Min')`

The `int64` will turn into a `float64` and for some reason I loose my `object` column.

`print (df3.dtypes)`

```
print (df3.dtypes)
B    float64
C    float64
dtype: object
```

Since I want to interpolate the columns differently based on this distinction in an subsequent step (after concatenating the `df` with another `df`), I need them to maintain their original `dtype`. My real `df` has far more columns of each type, for which reason I am looking for a solution that does not depend on calling the columns individually by their label.

Is there a way to maintain their `dtype` throughout the reindexing? Or is there a way how I can assign them their `dtype` afterwards (they are the only columns consisiting only of integers besides NANs)? 
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is [impossible](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions), because if you get at least one `NaN` value in some column, `int` is converted to `float`.

```
index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq="min") 
df2 = df.reindex(index)

print (df2)
                       A     B    C
2016-10-08 13:57:00   in  5.61  1.0
2016-10-08 13:58:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 13:59:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:00:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:01:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:02:00   in  8.05  1.0
2016-10-08 14:03:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:04:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:05:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:06:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:07:00   in  7.92  0.0
2016-10-08 14:08:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:09:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:10:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:11:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:12:00   in  7.98  0.0
2016-10-08 14:13:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:14:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:15:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:16:00  NaN   NaN  NaN
2016-10-08 14:17:00  out  8.18  0.0

print (df2.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
C    float64
dtype: object
```

But if you use parameter `fill_value` in [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), `dtypes` are not changed:

```
index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq="min") 
df2 = df.reindex(index, fill_value=0)

print (df2)
                       A     B  C
2016-10-08 13:57:00   in  5.61  1
2016-10-08 13:58:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 13:59:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:00:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:01:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:02:00   in  8.05  1
2016-10-08 14:03:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:04:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:05:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:06:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:07:00   in  7.92  0
2016-10-08 14:08:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:09:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:10:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:11:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:12:00   in  7.98  0
2016-10-08 14:13:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:14:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:15:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:16:00    0  0.00  0
2016-10-08 14:17:00  out  8.18  0

print (df2.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
C      int64
dtype: object
```

Better is to use `method='ffill` in `reindex`:

```
index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq="min") 
df2 = df.reindex(index, method='ffill')

print (df2)
                       A     B  C
2016-10-08 13:57:00   in  5.61  1
2016-10-08 13:58:00   in  5.61  1
2016-10-08 13:59:00   in  5.61  1
2016-10-08 14:00:00   in  5.61  1
2016-10-08 14:01:00   in  5.61  1
2016-10-08 14:02:00   in  8.05  1
2016-10-08 14:03:00   in  8.05  1
2016-10-08 14:04:00   in  8.05  1
2016-10-08 14:05:00   in  8.05  1
2016-10-08 14:06:00   in  8.05  1
2016-10-08 14:07:00   in  7.92  0
2016-10-08 14:08:00   in  7.92  0
2016-10-08 14:09:00   in  7.92  0
2016-10-08 14:10:00   in  7.92  0
2016-10-08 14:11:00   in  7.92  0
2016-10-08 14:12:00   in  7.98  0
2016-10-08 14:13:00   in  7.98  0
2016-10-08 14:14:00   in  7.98  0
2016-10-08 14:15:00   in  7.98  0
2016-10-08 14:16:00   in  7.98  0
2016-10-08 14:17:00  out  8.18  0

print (df2.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
C      int64
dtype: object
```

---

If you use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), you can get column `A` back by [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), but unfortunately there is still a problem with `float`:

```
df3 = df.set_index('A', append=True)
        .unstack()
        .resample('Min', fill_method='ffill')
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1)
print (df3)
                       A     B    C
DATE_TIME                          
2016-10-08 13:57:00   in  5.61  1.0
2016-10-08 13:58:00   in  5.61  1.0
2016-10-08 13:59:00   in  5.61  1.0
2016-10-08 14:00:00   in  5.61  1.0
2016-10-08 14:01:00   in  5.61  1.0
2016-10-08 14:02:00   in  8.05  1.0
2016-10-08 14:03:00   in  8.05  1.0
2016-10-08 14:04:00   in  8.05  1.0
2016-10-08 14:05:00   in  8.05  1.0
2016-10-08 14:06:00   in  8.05  1.0
2016-10-08 14:07:00   in  7.92  0.0
2016-10-08 14:08:00   in  7.92  0.0
2016-10-08 14:09:00   in  7.92  0.0
2016-10-08 14:10:00   in  7.92  0.0
2016-10-08 14:11:00   in  7.92  0.0
2016-10-08 14:12:00   in  7.98  0.0
2016-10-08 14:13:00   in  7.98  0.0
2016-10-08 14:14:00   in  7.98  0.0
2016-10-08 14:15:00   in  7.98  0.0
2016-10-08 14:16:00   in  7.98  0.0
2016-10-08 14:17:00  out  8.18  0.0

print (df3.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
C    float64
dtype: object
```

I modified a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39176650/2901002) for casting to `int:

```
int_cols = df.select_dtypes(['int64']).columns
print (int_cols)
Index(['C'], dtype='object')

index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq="s")
df2 = df.reindex(index)

for col in df2:
    if col == int_cols: 
        df2[col].ffill(inplace=True)
        df2[col] = df2[col].astype(int)
    elif df2[col].dtype == float:
        df2[col].interpolate(inplace=True)
    else:
        df2[col].ffill(inplace=True)
        
#print (df2)

print (df2.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
C      int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess my problem is now, that I can't linearly interpolate the `float64` as a next step, because all the newly created timesteps are filled. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176402/upsampling-a-time-series-with-different-conditions-for-float64-vs-object-and-int). This a link to my original question, I had just today realized that there was an issue with the dtype in the accepted solution, which is why I posted this new question. Do you think what I really want is even possible?

Comment: I add solution, please check last update. Thank you for accepting!

Comment: Cool! The code worked like that on my example `df` but to make it work with my real `df` with multiple columns of each type I had to modify following line `if col == int_cols.all():` because I did get the error:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` . Now it seems to work just fine! Thanks again!