# compare two dataframes original and output and return rows from output that do not have matching in original

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

i have two dfs original , output with same number of columns but different number of rows.

```
import pandas as pd
original = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
output = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 4,9], 'B': [4, 5, 7,8]})
```

**original**

```
    A   B
    1   4
    2   5
    3   6
```

**output**

```
    A   B
    1   4
    2   5
    4   7
    9   8
```

i want to compare output with original and get the extra rows(last two rows in this example) from output that do not have matching in original.

**diff_df**

```
    A   B
    4   7
    9   8
```

i have tried few stackoverflow suggestions using concat, merge etc, but not getting what i want, can someone help? tried some stuff using pyspark as well but no luck, any solution using pyspark or pandas is fine

Comment: Does `equals()` method of pandas help you?

Comment: [subtract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract.html?highlight=subtract#pyspark-sql-dataframe-subtract) - This is equivalent to EXCEPT DISTINCT in SQL.

Comment: **very** similar, by the way: 
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/48647534/12846804
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/54535258/12846804

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
>>> (original.merge(output, how='outer', indicator=True)
             .query("_merge == 'right_only'")[original.columns])

# OR

>>> (original.merge(output, how='outer', indicator=True)
             .loc[lambda x: x.pop('_merge') == 'right_only'])

   A  B
3  4  7
4  9  8
```

Without filtering:

```
>>> original.merge(output, how='outer', indicator=True)

   A  B      _merge
0  1  4        both
1  2  5        both
2  3  6   left_only
3  4  7  right_only
4  9  8  right_only
```

More about [merge dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/15239951)

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner with pandas:

```py
diff_df = output[ output != original.reindex_like(output) ].dropna()

     A    B
2  4.0  7.0
3  9.0  8.0
```

This views rows that differ, after taking care to adjust the size of `original` so as to fit size of `output`.

Why floats instead of integers? The reindexing, because it adds a number of `NaN` to fill the new rows, is responsible for columns 'int' dtype turning to 'float'. If your actual data really are integers and you would like to keep it as such, then add `.astype('int')` after `.dropna()`:

```py
   A  B
2  4  7
3  9  8
```

More on dtype not conserved while augmenting index: e.g. [Is there a way to prevent dtype from changing from Int64 to float64 when reindexing/upsampling a time-series?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39219023/12846804).

Answer (score 0):

In pandas you can utilize the indicator parameter in merge:

```
# pandas
merged_df = original.merge(output, how='outer', indicator=True)

    A   B   _merge
0   1   4   both
1   2   5   both
2   3   6   left_only
3   4   7   right_only
4   9   8   right_only

merged_df[merged_df['_merge'] == 'right_only'].drop(columns=['_merge'])

    A   B
3   4   7
4   9   8
```

It will create an additional column with the information from which table comes the record. It can be then used to get the necessary records.

In pyspark you can use anti join:

```
original_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(original)
output_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(output)

output_sdf.join(original_sdf, how='left_anti', on=['A', 'B']).show()

+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  4|  7|
|  9|  8|
+---+---+
```

Comment: You can use `merged_df[merged_df.pop('_merge') == 'right_only']` instead of `drop`

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

original = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

output = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 4, 9], 'B': [4, 5, 7, 8]})

def g(original, output):

```
"""Compares two dataframes and returns the rows from the second dataframe that do not have a matching row in the first dataframe.

Args:
    original: The first dataframe.
    output: The second dataframe.

Returns:
    A dataframe containing the rows from the second dataframe that do not have a matching row in the first dataframe.
"""

diff_df = output.loc[~output.isin(original).all(axis=1)]
return diff_df
```

diff_df = g(original.copy(), output.copy())
print(diff_df)

Output:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 |
| 9 | 8 |

This solution works by first creating a new dataframe, diff_df, which is a copy of the output dataframe. Then, we use the ~output.isin(original).all(axis=1) expression to select the rows in diff_df that do not have a matching row in original. The all(axis=1) function returns True if all of the values in a row are also present in the other dataframe, and False otherwise.

The loc function is then used to extract the selected rows from diff_df and return them as a new dataframe.

Comment: Isn't this writing odd? I mean, why make a function for one line? Even inside the function, you wouldn't have to assign an intermediate variable to return.

Comment: Benefits of using a function

Readability: The function makes the code more readable and easier to maintain. It is clear what the function does, and it is easy to follow the logic.
Reusability: The function can be reused in other parts of the code, which can save time and effort.
Testability: The function can be easily tested to ensure that it is working correctly.  I  also would like to remind that there is no one right way to write code, and that different people have different styles.

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.subtract(other: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame)`

Return a new DataFrame containing rows in this DataFrame but not in another

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1), ("a", 1), ("b", 3), ("c", 4)], ["C1", "C2"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1), ("a", 1), ("b", 3)], ["C1", "C2"])
df1.subtract(df2).show()
+---+---+
| C1| C2|
+---+---+
|  c|  4|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```py
import pandas as pd

original = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
output = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 4, 9], 'B': [4, 5, 7, 8]})

merged = pd.merge(original, output, on=['A', 'B'], how='outer', indicator=True)
diff_df_pandas = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only'][['A', 'B']]

print("Pandas Result:")
print(diff_df_pandas)

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("difference").getOrCreate()

original_spark = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)], ['A', 'B'])
output_spark = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4), (2, 5), (4, 7), (9, 8)], ['A', 'B'])

diff_df_spark = output_spark.subtract(original_spark)

print("\nPySpark Result:")
diff_df_spark.show()
```